# How do you know an edit request was successfully added to the edit suggestion queue?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I attempted to add the tag [exfat](/questions/tagged/exfat) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537878/how-to-mount-a-exfat-partition-in-ubuntu-11-04) in Stack Overflow. After I submitted the edit I received the following message which I expected.

> You do not have edit privileges. Your edit will be placed in a queue
>   until it is peer reviewed.

But I also received the following error message which I did not expect.

> Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
>     users with less than 1500 reputation can't create new tags.
>     The tag 'exfat' is new. Try using an existing tag instead.

The last time I attempted this was on a different exchange and my recollection is that there I received a completion message of sorts saying the edit was queued to be looked at.

Is the difference here because the tag apparently does not exist yet in Stack Overflow?

Is this the way this feature should work? Is not a suggestion to add a new tag potentially as valid as any other edit suggestion?

Comment: That *particular* question obviously does not belong on Stack Overflow, as it has nothing to do with programming. Likewise, I'm not sure that we need an `[exfat]` tag, as I don't think there will be that many programming questions asked about a specific file system.

Comment: All questions which I think are far above my kharma level. And I think the meta question of how the system should respond in this situation might still be worth considering regardless of the validity of either the question on SO or my suggested edit to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check your suggested edits by going to your profile, selecting the activity tab and filtering by suggestions. [As you can see](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348415/irrational-john?tab=activity&sort=suggestions), you have no suggested edits on Stack Overflow. You'll also see a message at the top of the post that looks like this:

> **Thanks for your edit!**
>   This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed.

The "you do not have edit privileges" is not really a message in response to something you did. It just appears at the top of the edit form for everyone without editing privileges.

The "your edit couldn't be submitted" part is, though. Since you can't create new tags, you can't suggest edits that, if approved, would create a new tag, either. Your suggested edit was discarded in this case.

Comment: Why does not being able to *create* a new tag imply that one should also not even be allowed to merely *suggest* the creation of a new tag?

Comment: @irrationalJohn 'cos the tag system is supposed to be complete. New tags are rarely created, even by high-reps. Except when the site is new. Not applicable to SO.

Answer (score 2):

On Stack Overflow, you need to a reputation of 1500, to create new tags. This means you also need that reputation to suggest a tag, as it is you who is creating the tag, not the user who approves the edit you suggested.

Once you reach a reputation of 1500, you can edit tags (which also means adding new tags) without suggesting an edit.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

(The screenshots are from Programmers, where my reputation allows me to edit tags, and to suggest edits.)